# How to draw line between two views in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, draw

I want to Draw lines from one object to another object. Like a Matching object game. I want Swift language with UIKit Use. Here I attach the Sample Screenshot.

[image]

Does anyone have experience with this? then please help me.

Comment: You might want to look at my LinkSame app (it's free) for an example of doing this. I overlay a transparent view in front of the game board and draw the lines in that view.

Comment: @DuncanC Well it's not like your "answer" has any actual content. It is basically an acknowledgment that the question is too broad.

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't use SpriteKit for this?

Comment: @Shadowrun it will work. do you have any idea how can it be possible in SpriteKit?

Comment: Do you need the lines between your objects to be different colors, or can they all be the same color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of choices.

You can create a custom subclass of UIView that implements the `draw(_:)` function to draw custom content. That view would need to big enough to enclose all of your custom drawing. You'd fill most of the view with clear, and then draw the lines you want using Core Graphics.

The other option is to use Core Animation layers. You could add a `CAShapeLayer` to your view's layer, set up the shape layer with the desired line thickness and color, and add a path to the layer containing the lines you want to draw. (Note that if you use CAShapeLayers, all the lines drawn in a single shape layer will be the same color. You'll need multiple shape layers in order to draw in multiple colors.)

Both approaches will require some research. Shape layers are more efficient and take better advantage of the graphics hardware on iOS devices, but using them has a fairly steep learning curve.

You should be able to google examples of both approaches. Try search phrases like "Custom drawing in a UIView" and "drawing with CAShapeLayer". I wrote a little demo app called [**OvalView**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/OvalView.git) that demonstrates how to create a UIView subclass that manages a shape layer.

### Edit:

I adapted the code from my sample app into a demo called LinesBetweenViews. The new demo has a custom UIView that draws lines between any pairs of subviews you put into it.

Here is a screenshot of the demo:

[image]

If you answer my questions I can upload the demo app to Github so you can look at it.

### Edit #2

See [this Github repo](https://github.com/DuncanMC/LinesBetweenViews.git) for a sample project that draws lines between pairs of subviews.

Comment: Thank you for the Reply. Do you have any class files for a demo? so I can review and check if it will work or not.

Comment: The Github project [**OvalView**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/OvalView.git), for example, creates views that draw rounded rectangles. It illustrates how to create a subclass of `UIView` that has a `CAShapeLayer` as it's backing layer.

Comment: For your application you'd change the method `createPath()` in the class OvalView to create a path that contained a series of straight lines rather than a single rounded rectangle. Your OvalView would be as large as your entire "game board" so you could draw your lines to match all your pairs of shapes.

Comment: Yes, eject I want that you attach the screenshot. you can upload the demo on github. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need the lines between your objects to be different colors, or can they all be the same color? (All lines drawn by a CAShapeLayer are the same color)

Comment: In your sample picture you seem to have 2 line colors: Black and white. Will your lines always be a single color? One of 2 colors? Or an arbitrary number of colors?

Comment: it's always single color.

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Does this help you?